# How to lock apps, photos?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I want to lock apps and photos on my phone. I have upgraded my phone to Window 10 Mobile. Is there any way to do this?

I know there is **apps** corner and **kids** corner. But the problem is I set password to my phone. while accessing apps or kids corner it uses same password so there is no sense to use app, kids corner. Is there any way to set **different password** to apps or kids corner?

Comment: What do you mean by "locking" apps or photos?

Comment: If you want a app like App locker in Android, I think it may not be possible in Windows 10. However if you want that if you give your phone to someone that person may not be able to access certain content or apps on your phone then apps corner and kids corner can help you. But locking apps like in Android, I think, is not possible at this time.

Comment: @Amandeep You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a app like App locker in Android, I think it may not be possible in Windows 10. However if you want that if you give your phone to someone that person may not be able to access certain content or apps on your phone then apps corner and kids corner can help you. But locking apps like in Android, I think, is not possible at this time.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know there is apps corner and kids corner. But the problem is I set password to my phone. while accessing apps or kids corner it uses same password so there is no sense to use app, kids corner. is there any way to set **different password** to apps or kids corner?

Answer (score 1):

You cant lock app in windows mobile like in android, but there are ways to hide the images using image lockers. one such app to lock/hide your photos is given below >
File Vault

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/file-vault/9wzdncrdk6xc

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it's impossible to lock apps in windows phone. And if you want to lock your photos in your phone, u have to move your photos into sort of file locker apps. You'll be able to find it in store easily.